# Tela preta no MySQL Workbench

Tags: linux, mysql, mint

Uso Linux Mint e ao instalar o MySQL Workbench ele fica como na imagem.

Já reinstalei, apaguei tudo, baixei outras versões e não consigo nada...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Experimente abrir o workbench na linha de comandos com parâmetro `--force-sw-` ou  `--force-opengl-render`e veja se algum melhora.

Comment: Consegui abrir ele assim, sudo mysql-workbench, porém atribui acessos de root ao meu usuário para abrir tal e fica preto... Mas enfim ache uma solução, obrigado!

Comment: Considere colocar uma resposta com a solução do seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui abrir ele assim, sudo mysql-workbench, porém atribui acessos de root ao meu usuário para abrir tal e fica preto... Mas enfim ache uma solução, obrigado!